# JVM crashes after migrating to 64bit

Tags: java, crash, garbage-collection, jvm, 64-bit

My application started crashing after we migrate it to 64bit. The crash is occuring every 2-3 days on our production linux server. We are using jdk1.6.0_15-x86_64. The crash is happening at the same place when my application uses the Xalan transformer to convert XSLT to HTML.

I have confirmed that this is not happening on our 32bit server and not happening when the application doesn't perform the XSLT to HTML convertion. So it happens only when convertion happens on 64bit server.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the content from the dump file

```
    ######################################
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b288a0457d1, pid=9161, tid=1213643072
    #
    # JRE version: 6.0_15-b03
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [libjvm.so+0x3837d1]
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x0000000044267800):  JavaThread "[default]-careers_ente_com-/resume_list_intermediate.html-76.125.192.80-B8FF993FA76C999A3568847142ECA47C.JS1-Thread-57504" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=18390, stack(0x000000004846b000,0x000000004856c000)]

    siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=128 (), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

    Registers:
    RAX=0x0000000000000001, RBX=0x002f840f1fb10f4c, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000001
    RSP=0x0000000048569d50, RBP=0x0000000048569d70, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x0000000043d7c830
    R8 =0x0000000000000001, R9 =0x00002aaab073f9d8, R10=0x00002b288a582c2a, R11=0x0000000044269a98
    R12=0x00002aaab07431c8, R13=0x0000000000000008, R14=0x0000000044267800, R15=0x0000000048569dd0
    RIP=0x00002b288a0457d1, EFL=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
      TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

    Stack: [0x000000004846b000,0x000000004856c000],  sp=0x0000000048569d50,  free space=1019k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [libjvm.so+0x3837d1]
    V  [libjvm.so+0x3a2f72]
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet.addParameter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+8
    j  hrxmlresume2html.topLevel(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/DOM;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/dtm/DTMAxisIterator;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;)V+218
    j  hrxmlresume2html.transform(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/DOM;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/dtm/DTMAxisIterator;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;)V+24
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet.transform(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/DOM;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;)V+9
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;Ljava/lang/String;)V+152
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Ljavax/xml/transform/Result;)V+119
    j  com.ente.hrxml.resume.HtmlConverter.toHtml(Lorg/jdom/Document;)Ljava/lang/String;+49
    j  com.ente.er.form.hrxmledit.generateHtmlResumeBuilder(Lcom/ente/erom/candidate/Candidate;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+42
    j  com.ente.er.form.hrxmledit.save()Lcom/ente/services/webui/UIStatus;+574
    j  com.ente.er.form.hrxmledit.postprocess()Lcom/ente/services/webui/UIStatus;+202

    Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet.addParameter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+8
    j  hrxmlresume2html.topLevel(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/DOM;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/dtm/DTMAxisIterator;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;)V+218
    j  hrxmlresume2html.transform(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/DOM;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/dtm/DTMAxisIterator;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;)V+24
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet.transform(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/DOM;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;)V+9
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;Ljava/lang/String;)V+152
    j  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Ljavax/xml/transform/Result;)V+119
    j  com.ente.hrxml.resume.HtmlConverter.toHtml(Lorg/jdom/Document;)Ljava/lang/String;+49
    j  com.ente.er.form.hrxmledit.generateHtmlResumeBuilder(Lcom/ente/erom/candidate/Candidate;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+42
    j  com.ente.er.form.hrxmledit.save()Lcom/ente/services/webui/UIStatus;+574
    j  com.ente.er.form.hrxmledit.postprocess()Lcom/ente/services/webui/UIStatus;+202
    J  com.ente.services.webui.Form.process()Lcom/ente/services/webui/UIStatus;
    j  com.ente.er.form.hrxmledit.process()Lcom/ente/services/webui/UIStatus;+1
    J  com.ente.services.webui.Form.eval(Lcom/ente/services/webui/Request;)V
    j  com.ente.services.webui.Nav.evalForm()V+232
    j  com.ente.services.webui.Nav.initPage()Lcom/ente/services/webui/Nav;+151
    j  com.ente.er.ERecruiter.getER(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Z)Lcom/ente/er/ERecruiter;+353
    j  com.ente.er.ERecruiter.getER(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)Lcom/ente/er/ERecruiter;+3
    j  jsp__careers_2eente_2ecom_80___resume_list_intermediate_2ehtml._jspService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+114
    j  org.gjt.jsp.HttpJspPageImpl.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+3
    j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+29
    j  org.gjt.jsp.JspServlet$Page.process(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+937
    j  org.gjt.jsp.JspServlet.xservice(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;)V+39
    j  org.gjt.jsp.JspServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+162
    j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+29
    j  org.apache.jserv.JServConnection.processRequest()V+627
    j  org.apache.jserv.JServConnection.run()V+80
    j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
    =>0x0000000044267800 JavaThread "[default]-careers_ente_com-/resume_list_intermediate.html-76.125.192.80-B8FF993FA76C999A3568847142ECA47C.JS1-Thread-57504" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=18390, stack(0x000000004846b000,0x000000004856c000)]
      0x00000000447a1800 JavaThread "3C758A73EA22FCDE9E41A2149C9E8F43.JS1-Thread-54838" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14006, stack(0x000000004836a000,0x000000004846b000)]
      0x00000000446a5000 JavaThread "108.243.174.151-3C758A73EA22FCDE9E41A2149C9E8F43.JS1-Thread-54742" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=13872, stack(0x000000004745b000,0x000000004755c000)]
      0x000000004400a800 JavaThread "TaskManager-IdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20114, stack(0x0000000047057000,0x0000000047158000)]
      0x0000000044a8a800 JavaThread "TaskManager-IdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9567, stack(0x0000000046d54000,0x0000000046e55000)]
      0x000000004479a800 JavaThread "TaskManager-IdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9566, stack(0x0000000046c53000,0x0000000046d54000)]
      0x0000000044b2d800 JavaThread "TaskManager-IdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9565, stack(0x0000000046b52000,0x0000000046c53000)]
      0x0000000043f6b800 JavaThread "TaskManager-IdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9564, stack(0x00000000439a4000,0x0000000043aa5000)]
      0x0000000044214000 JavaThread "TaskManager-IdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9327, stack(0x0000000043ba6000,0x0000000043ca7000)]
      0x0000000044018000 JavaThread "TaskManager-IdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9326, stack(0x0000000043aa5000,0x0000000043ba6000)]
      0x00000000441bc800 JavaThread "TaskManager-IdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9324, stack(0x0000000042893000,0x0000000042994000)]
      0x0000000044a89000 JavaThread "TaskManager-IdleThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9323, stack(0x0000000040ec5000,0x0000000040fc6000)]
      0x0000000044923800 JavaThread "internal_careers_ente_com-Timer-Timer-13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9318, stack(0x00000000438a3000,0x00000000439a4000)]
      0x0000000045643800 JavaThread "ImportAgent-Timer-Timer-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9317, stack(0x00000000437a2000,0x00000000438a3000)]
      0x00000000461e9000 JavaThread "internal_careers_ente_com-Retry-Timer-Timer-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9316, stack(0x00000000436a1000,0x00000000437a2000)]
      0x000000004466a800 JavaThread "XPostDirector-Timer-Timer-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9315, stack(0x00000000435a0000,0x00000000436a1000)]
      0x0000000044667800 JavaThread "internal_careers_ente_com-EventInformant1554828645.1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9314, stack(0x000000004349f000,0x00000000435a0000)]
      0x0000000044798800 JavaThread "internal_careers_ente_com-EventInformant1554828645.2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9313, stack(0x000000004339e000,0x000000004349f000)]
      0x0000000044797800 JavaThread "internal_careers_ente_com-EventInformant1554828645.3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9312, stack(0x000000004329d000,0x000000004339e000)]
      0x0000000043ff1000 JavaThread "internal_careers_ente_com-EventInformant1554828645.4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9311, stack(0x000000004319c000,0x000000004329d000)]
      0x0000000044795000 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-Retry-Timer-Timer-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9310, stack(0x000000004309b000,0x000000004319c000)]
      0x0000000044792800 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-EventInformant190296991.1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9309, stack(0x0000000042f9a000,0x000000004309b000)]
      0x0000000046233800 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-EventInformant190296991.2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9308, stack(0x0000000042e99000,0x0000000042f9a000)]
      0x0000000046231800 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-EventInformant190296991.3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9307, stack(0x0000000042d98000,0x0000000042e99000)]
      0x0000000046231000 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-EventInformant190296991.4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9306, stack(0x0000000042c97000,0x0000000042d98000)]
      0x0000000044c0c000 JavaThread "LDAPConnThread ldap5.ente.com:389" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9305, stack(0x0000000042b96000,0x0000000042c97000)]
      0x0000000044c0a000 JavaThread "LDAPConnThread ldap5.ente.com:389" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9304, stack(0x0000000042a95000,0x0000000042b96000)]
      0x0000000044c0d800 JavaThread "LDAPConnThread ldap4.ente.com:389" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9303, stack(0x0000000042994000,0x0000000042a95000)]
      0x0000000044c07800 JavaThread "LDAPConnThread ldap4.ente.com:389" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9301, stack(0x0000000042691000,0x0000000042792000)]
      0x000000004597d000 JavaThread "LDAPConnThread ldap4.ente.com:389" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9300, stack(0x0000000041723000,0x0000000041824000)]
      0x000000004404e000 JavaThread "OracleTimeoutPollingThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9226, stack(0x0000000042792000,0x0000000042893000)]
      0x00002aab10677000 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-Timer-Timer-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9224, stack(0x0000000042590000,0x0000000042691000)]
      0x00002aab1059a000 JavaThread "SessionReaper-Timer-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9223, stack(0x000000004248f000,0x0000000042590000)]
      0x00002aab11230000 JavaThread "DebugListener-1234-Thread-16" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9222, stack(0x000000004238e000,0x000000004248f000)]
      0x00002aab10628800 JavaThread "ImportAgent-Timer-Timer-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9221, stack(0x00000000419ae000,0x0000000041aaf000)]
      0x00002aab106b0800 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-Retry-Timer-Timer-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9219, stack(0x000000004020b000,0x000000004030c000)]
      0x00002aab104c9800 JavaThread "XPostDirector-Timer-Timer-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9218, stack(0x00000000405c3000,0x00000000406c4000)]
      0x00002aab1056c000 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-EventInformant74291610.1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9216, stack(0x000000004228d000,0x000000004238e000)]
      0x00002aab1053e000 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-EventInformant74291610.2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9215, stack(0x000000004218c000,0x000000004228d000)]
      0x00002aab1048a800 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-EventInformant74291610.3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9214, stack(0x0000000041cd6000,0x0000000041dd7000)]
      0x00002aab104e9000 JavaThread "careers_ente_com-EventInformant74291610.4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9213, stack(0x00000000408ef000,0x00000000409f0000)]
      0x00002aab1021d800 JavaThread "CacheReporter-Timer-2" [_thread_blocked, id=9212, stack(0x000000004208b000,0x000000004218c000)]
      0x00002aab1000f800 JavaThread "StatsReporter-Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9211, stack(0x0000000041f8a000,0x000000004208b000)]
      0x00002aab10025800 JavaThread "LDAPConnThread ldap5.ente.com:389" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9210, stack(0x0000000041e89000,0x0000000041f8a000)]
      0x000000004406d800 JavaThread "LDAPConnThread ldap5.ente.com:389" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9209, stack(0x0000000041622000,0x0000000041723000)]
      0x000000004401e000 JavaThread "Periodic Collector-Timer-0" [_thread_blocked, id=9208, stack(0x00000000418ad000,0x00000000419ae000)]
      0x00002aab10003000 JavaThread "Thread-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9186, stack(0x0000000040a6f000,0x0000000040b70000)]
      0x0000000043e0d000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9184, stack(0x0000000041ad4000,0x0000000041bd5000)]
      0x0000000043e0a000 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9183, stack(0x0000000041380000,0x0000000041481000)]
      0x0000000043e05800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9182, stack(0x0000000040753000,0x0000000040854000)]
      0x0000000043e03800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9181, stack(0x000000004010a000,0x000000004020b000)]
      0x0000000043ddf800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9180, stack(0x00000000414fe000,0x00000000415ff000)]
      0x0000000043dde000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9179, stack(0x000000004127f000,0x0000000041380000)]
      0x0000000043d7f000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9173, stack(0x000000004107d000,0x000000004117e000)]

    Other Threads:
      0x0000000043dd7000 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000403e4000,0x00000000404e5000] [id=9178]
      0x0000000043e0f000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000041bd5000,0x0000000041cd6000] [id=9185]

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
    [0x0000000043d7c830] OsrList_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000044267800

    Heap
     PSYoungGen      total 471680K, used 20796K [0x00002aaaed940000, 0x00002aab0abe0000, 0x00002aab0abe0000)
      eden space 465664K, 4% used [0x00002aaaed940000,0x00002aaaeed8f0a8,0x00002aab0a000000)
      from space 6016K, 0% used [0x00002aab0a000000,0x00002aab0a000000,0x00002aab0a5e0000)
      to   space 5760K, 0% used [0x00002aab0a640000,0x00002aab0a640000,0x00002aab0abe0000)
     PSOldGen        total 955776K, used 110793K [0x00002aaab33e0000, 0x00002aaaed940000, 0x00002aaaed940000)
      object space 955776K, 11% used [0x00002aaab33e0000,0x00002aaaba012550,0x00002aaaed940000)
     PSPermGen       total 43072K, used 42828K [0x00002aaaadfe0000, 0x00002aaab09f0000, 0x00002aaab33e0000)
      object space 43072K, 99% used [0x00002aaaadfe0000,0x00002aaab09b32f8,0x00002aaab09f0000)

    VM Arguments:
    jvm_args: -Xms1400m -Xmx1400m -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol -Dsecurity.provider.1=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider -Der.logfile=var/log/e-Recruiter.log -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=7200 -DHTMLDOCPATH=/usr/bin/htmldoc -Doracle.jdbc.V8Compatible=true -Dldap.enable=true -Dldap.path=ldap://recruiter:recruiter@ldap4.ente.com:389,ldap5.ente.com:389,ldap6.ente.com:389/er-10.15.0.2 
    java_command: org.apache.jserv.JServ etc/jserv.properties
    Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

    Environment Variables:
    JAVA_HOME=
    PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
    USERNAME=root
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ente-20080222/Sun/jdk1.6.0_15-x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/ente-20080222/Sun/jdk1.6.0_15-x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/local/ente-20080222/Sun/jdk1.6.0_15-x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/local/ente/Oracle/client/lib
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    _JAVA_SR_SIGNUM=12

    Signal Handlers:
    SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x6bdd00], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x6bdd00], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x594ed0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x594ed0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x594ed0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x594ed0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
    SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x597690], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x5973e0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
    SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x5973e0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x5973e0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS:CentOS release 5.4 (Final)

    uname:Linux 2.6.18-164.15.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Mar 17 11:30:06 EDT 2010 x86_64
    libc:glibc 2.5 NPTL 2.5 
    rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC infinity, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity
    load average:0.00 0.00 0.00

    CPU:total 2 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 26 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2

    Memory: 4k page, physical 4044572k(274688k free), swap 2031608k(2031532k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.1-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_15-b03), built on Jul  2 2009 15:26:16 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)

    time: Sun Aug 12 21:34:09 2012
    elapsed time: 162182 seconds
```

Comment: do you use the same memory settings for both the 32bit and 64bit jvms?  be aware that the same code running in a 64bit jvm will use a fair bit more memory due to the change in reference(pointer) sizes.

Comment: Update 15 is very old and lots of bugs have been fixed since then, I would try Java 6 update 35 or Java 7 update 7. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-136954.html

Comment: In 32bit version our application used to configure using -Xms800m -Xmx800m and now in 64bit verion it has been increased to -Xms1400m -Xmx1400m

Answer (score 0):

```
 PSPermGen       total 43072K, used 42828K [0x00002aaaadfe0000, 0x00002aaab09f0000, 0x00002aaab33e0000)
      object space 43072K, 99% used [0x00002aaaadfe0000,0x00002aaab09b32f8,0x00002aaab09f0000)
```

It seems your permgen is being corrupted which could be due to the fact that your code trying to load libraries. I suspect the libraries being loaded by following code may not be compatible with 64 bit JVM.

Before filing a bug with JVM, I would  check in program following lines of code, which seems culprit.

```
  com.ente.hrxml.resume.HtmlConverter.toHtml(Lorg/jdom/Document;)Ljava/lang/String;+49
```

Comment: I would suggest add XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushin also

Comment: Is there a way to find whether the libraries are compatible with 64bit JVM?

Comment: May be check the version of libraries and go to their website and see release notes.

Comment: @jtahlborn: though I agree with your statement, this is not issue with heap, this is issue with Permgen.

Comment: @jtahlborn/Nambari - checked the permgen size when the application doesn't crash, it always shows 99% but the total and used is lower than 40M. So I believe the 40M is only allocated total and it is not the maximum permgen. Thoughts? –

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest increasing the perm gen space (-XX:MaxPermSize) and enabling GC on it (-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled) -- 40M isn't much!  If you are loading a lot of libraries, I'd also suggest enabling class unloading (-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled).  Note that if you really do have a memory leak, this will only give you more breathing room between crashes, you still need to fix the underlying cause.

Comment: I checked the permgen size when the application doesn't crash, it always shows 99% but the total and used is lower than 40M. So I believe the 40M is only allocated total and it is not the maximum permgen. Thoughts?